# How to filter mails by sender using imap-simple and mailparser on nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, imap

I've found how to filter by the time and subject, but there isn't attribute like
"sender" for mail object.
The code below:

```
    getMail(mail, pwd, IMAPhost, time, subject, resultHTML) {
      var config = {
        imap: {
          ...
        }
      };

      imaps.connect(config).then(async function (connection) {
        await connection.openBox('INBOX');
        var searchCriteria = ['UNSEEN'];
        var fetchOptions = {
          bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT', ''],
        };

        const messages = await connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions);
        messages.forEach(function (item) {
          var all = _.find(item.parts, { "which": "" });
          var id = item.attributes.uid;

          var idHeader = "Imap-Id: " + id + "\r\n";
          simpleParser(idHeader + all.body, (err, mail) => {
            if (mail.subject === subject && time > mail.date) {
              console.log('Время письма ' + mail.date);
              return resultHTML(mail.html);
            } 
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

Below part of my output **all.body** (without current information):

```
Received: from .qloud-c.yandex.net (.qloud-c.yandex.net)
        by .qloud-c.yandex.net with LMTP
        for <mymail@yandex.ru>; Mon, 18 Jan 2021 18:35:01 +0300
Received: from server info (server info [])
        by .qloud-c.yandex.net (mxfront/Yandex) with ESMTPS id ;
Return-Path: sender@mail.ru
From: =?UTF-8?= <sender@mail.ru>
To: mymail@yandex.ru
```

Comment: You need the envelope fetch option. That will give you arrays of addresses: from, sender, to etc.

Comment: Can you put an example how to do that right, please? I made a lot of attempts, but all of them failed.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I haven't written javascript in at least a year, so writing working example code would take me hours, and I don't have hours to spare. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, thank you! No problem. I'll try again.